# How to combine two rasters, preferring the values of one over the other?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster

I have two rasters that I need to combine (not using the Combine tool). The values of the 1st raster are preferred to those of the 2nd raster, so I want to keep these values if they exist. Where the 1st raster has NoData values, I would like to keep the values of the 2nd raster. This should function similarly to the Update tool in ArcGIS, but instead of vector data we're working with rasters. I need to do this in ArcGIS (it's part of a model), but I'm also interested in other methods of achieving this.

Comment: Use `IsNull` and `Con` as illustrated in the answers at http://gis.stackexchange.com/search?q=isnull+con+arcgis.